# gulp build adding 2 hashes to few image file name

Tags: gulp, jhipster

I am struggling with a very strange issue with gulp build. I created a project using jhipster with angular 1. When I build the war for prod using mvn clean install -Pprod or just do gulp build, all my images files under content/images are copied properly to www/content/images. My HTML templates are minified and merged into 1 single app-f88bd0c8d7.js file under www/app folder. However, when I run the app and my index.html is opened, for few of the images I get 404 error even though those images are there in the war under content/images folder. The problem is with the name using which the images are being referred. For ex. my rev-manifest.json file under temp folder shows below entry - "fav-1.png": "fav-1-013b104b51.png", but this file is referred in my app-f88bd0c8d7.js as fav-1-013b104b51-57eab5e392.png, so if you notice its appending "-57eab5e392.png" extra. This happens only for few images(not same images, keeps on changing) every time I do gulp build.

I read quite a few forums on SO and went through open issues on git, but nowhere I see anyone facing this kind of issue. I tried below solutions but none worked:

1) Added a task for clearing gulp-cache as below and invoked it during gulp build -

```
var cache = require('gulp-cache');

gulp.task('clean', function () {
return del([config.dist], { dot: true });
});

gulp.task('build', ['clean'], function (cb) {
runSequence(['clearcache','copy', 'inject:vendor', 'ngconstant:prod', 'languages'], 'inject:app', 'inject:troubleshoot', 'assets:prod', cb);
});
```

2)Tried commenting out below lines :

```
a) .pipe(imagemin({optimizationLevel: 5, progressive: true, interlaced: true}))

b).pipe(rev())

c)gulp.watch(config.app + 'content/images/**', ['images']);
```

My jhipster version is 3.4.2 and gulp version is 3.9.1

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: a) and c) are not related to your issue, Only gulp-rev and rev-hash are relevant. Have you tried updating these 2 dependencies?

Comment: no.. let me try..

Comment: I tried updating the version to 7.1.2 from 7.0.0 but it has same issue. So I just commented out .pipe(rev()) and it worked. No hashing of files. Tried it last time as well, not sure why it didnt work. Anyways, it's working now. Will post the same as answer in case someone finds it useful.

Comment: It works in dev mode, I doubt it'll work in prod mode.

Comment: No, dev mode the build is not even kicked off rt.. the build kicks off only when I fire prod build..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my comment as answer : I tried updating the git-rev version to 7.1.2 from 7.0.0 but it has same issue. So I just commented out .pipe(rev()) and it worked. No hashing of files happening now. Tried it last time as well, not sure why it didnt work. Anyways, it's working now. Will post the same as answer in case someone finds it useful.

Comment: Be aware though that doing so is not enough because asset versioning is made for working with far future caching in browser. So unless you disabled cache headers in server in prod mode, your solution will create problems for your users who will use stale assets.

Comment: ok..ok, thanks for the info.. I had to get rid of gulp itself, since it was also creating other problems. For fonts, which I was loading over the web, it was removing those lines in prod build, second for JS libraries which I was loading over web and using in my app code, it was not correctly creating the source map file for it. It was mapping those functions to other angular libraries which I was loading via bower. I think I need to switch to grunt or webpack.